# DJANGO + SAML2 + CSRF

Tags: django, saml-2.0

I have to introduce SAML2 authentication in my Django Project.

My base app use CSRF Token that is provided by @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator in the main page.

For implementing SAML, I've added a new "login" button on main page (the one that set se csrf token cookie). The button send the SAML request to IDP. When I return from IDP to a landing page (a view in saml2 sub-app that reads the response) I got a 403 Forbidden error about CSRF Token.

I'm using OneLogin python Library (python3-saml). https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml

The landing page is the one that ends with: ?acs

What I want to know is if its a problem of my landing page or the IDP Response has to be binded with csrf token in some way.

[image]

Thanks.

NOTE: I've also tryed to add IDP domain in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to mark the SAML return view as `@csrf_exempt` as the IDP wouldn't know how to pass the Django-specific CSRF token.

Comment: Yeah. I had to this cheat because there is no way to have SAML response with my csrf token.

Comment: It's not a cheat, especially considering the SAML machinery will validate the SAML payload anyway. There's no way for a site that could do cross-site requests to be able to create a SAML payload that would pass that validation too.